# Why does this process.join() not make this program wait for all processes to finish?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to code a program (in Python) that isolates all points of a similar colour to a key from an image, and I've run into a problem when I tried to optimise it with multiprocessing. The processes don't all finish giving their results, with or without using .join().
The relevant (simplified) code is this:

```
def func(a,b,c,d,queue):
    #*...some code that takes a long time (2+ seconds)...*
    out = [a,b,c]
    index = d
    queue.put((out, index))
procs = []
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
for p in range(nP):
    #*...some code that calculates the parameters...*
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args = (a,b,c,d,q))
    proc.start()
    procs.append(proc)
values = []
kInds = []
while not q.empty():
    t = q.get()
    values.append(t[0])
    kInds.append(t[1])
    print(t)
#this bit V
for pro in procs:
    pro.join()
#*...rest of code...*
```

where the function being called `queue.put()`s a tuple of (a list of indices matching the colour key, the number key being matched to).

As far as I can tell, without the marked bit of code to join processes, the main process carries on and so some processes don't return all their results, as expected.
When I use the .join(), though, some of the processes still don't return all their values and the code then halts completely. If I put it before the q.get() clause, then the program just halts forever.
Is this the right way to make the program wait until all results are put on and read off the queue? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is more that `The processes don't all finish giving their results` rather than the placement of the `join`. Unless you have zero control over those processes, then you should probably be focusing on why those processes never finish, rather than trying to work around the issue in any way.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the master process reads from the queue faster than the child processes are pushing into it. So it will empty the queue while some of the children are still adding to it. The slow child processes can't be joined until the main process fetches from the queue. So you have a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be right! I've changed it to add a little delay before it declares the queue empty and that seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building robust python multiprocessing code has a number of pitfalls, the pre-built `multiprocessing.Pool` is a great tool but sometimes you find yourself wanting something more/different.

#### Race Conditions

With your code, you are running into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) where the queue is emptied by the main process before all child processes are done with their computation and have attempted to pass back their results. Furthermore the python documentation hints that the call to `queue.empty()` and `queue.qsize()` are not safe against race conditions in general. There are generally two ways (many more are possible) I commonly get around race conditions in a queue:

1. Know exactly how many results to expect:

`for _ in range(n_tasks): q.get()`

2. Each worker process should send a "I'm done" sentinel, and expect `n_workers` sentinels.

```
class Sentinel: pass
n_sentinels = 0
while True:
    item = q.get()
    if isinstance(item, Sentinel):
        n_sentinels += 1
        if n_sentinels == n_workers:
            break
    else:
        #process item
```

#### Deadlock

Another common problem while handling multiprocessing tasks with a queue can be [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock). In particular, `q.get` and `q.put` may not return right away, and may be waiting on another process or thread to either put something in the queue or take something out. Python's multiprocessing queues are backed by OS pipes, which cannot store an infinite amount of data in them before `q.put` will block. In your case the data is small, and it works fine to write all the data and wait for process completion before starting to read the data. This may stop working however when you move away from toy examples. In general, you should not attempt to join a process before reading all the data from the queue or else you may be waiting on the join in the main process while the child waits on `q.put` and will never join until something empties the queue. Robust multiprocessing code must also consider that things sometimes go wrong, so I would say to not necessarily always use, but always consider if you should use a timeout value for any queue or lock operations. When a timeout occurs, you may have the opportunity to go check for example if a child process exited with a nonzero exitcode (exception).

```
q = Queue()
workers = []
for _ in range(n_workers):
    p = Process(target=work_func, args=(a, b, q))
    workers.append(p)
    p.start()

while any(w.exitcode is None for w in workers): #while any worker is still running
    try:
        handle_results(q.get(True, 1)) #wait for at most 1 second before checking if any workers are still alive
    except queue.Empty:
        #perform other housekeeping while waiting

#for w in workers: w.join() #This is technically redundant to looping until all processes have an exitcode

while not q.empty(): #once we are single-threaded race conditions don't apply anymore, and this should be reliable.
    handle_results(q.get()) #handle any remaining queue items.
```

Answer (score 1):

`q.empty()` doesn't mean it's always going to be empty. And worse, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty) warn:

> Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. Because of
> multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.

You know how many results to expect, so read that many from the queue. Make sure that the process manages its errors so that all processes return something. You may want to put a timeout on the get just in case something goes terribly wrong with one of the subprocesses.

```
def func(a,b,c,d,queue):
    try:
        #*...some code that takes a long time (2+ seconds)...*
        out = [a,b,c]
        index = d
        queue.put((out, index))
    except:
        queue.put(None)
        raise

procs = []
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
for p in range(nP):
    #*...some code that calculates the parameters...*
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args = (a,b,c,d,q))
    proc.start()
    procs.append(proc)
values = []
kInds = []

for _ in range(nP):
    t = q.get()
    if t is not None:
        values.append(t[0])
        kInds.append(t[1])
        print(t)
    else:
        print('bad')
#this bit V
for pro in procs:
    pro.join()
```

Better yet, let Python do the work for you. Processing pools exist.

```
def func(a,b,c,d,queue):
    #*...some code that takes a long time (2+ seconds)...*
    out = [a,b,c]
    index = d
    return out, index

values = []
kInds = []

with multiprocessing.Pool(len(nP)) as pool:
    params_list = *...some code that calculates the parameters...*
    for t in pool.map(func, params_list):
        values.append(t[0])
        kInds.append(t[1])
```